# Best Linux for a single application & fast boot? (also How-to?)

Tags: linux, boot, performance

I'm looking for a way to run [Celtx](http://www.celtx.com),a screenwriting software on a Linux Distro and nothing else, no bluetooth, internet/WiFi, media, games, nothing, not even a desktop. Just boot up the OS and Bam! Celtx. Also, a fast boot would be great.

P.S. I'd need to automount a NTFS partition.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122717/custom-linux-distro-that-runs-just-one-program-nothing-else

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned by DaveParillo, any distibution can be stripped down to next to nothing. However, building a system from the ground up is probably preferable in your case. This is what [Arch Linux](http://archlinux.org) was designed for. If you are comfortable with this idea, continue...

--

1. Follow the [official](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Official_Arch_Linux_Install_Guide) or [beginner's](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners_Guide) installation guide to install the base system.

To mount your NTFS partition automatically, open up your /etc/fstab and add the following line (/dev/sdb1 being the NTFS partition and /mnt/device being the mount point):

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/device ntfs defaults 1 0
```

If you want to be able to log in automatically you will need to take a few extra steps. First, install [mingetty](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=13793) from the Arch User Respository (AUR). [Here](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_User_Guidelines#Installing_Packages_from_the_AUR) is a small guide to help you do that if you are unfamiliar with Arch Linux.
Next, open up /etc/inittab and change the line that looks like:

```
c1:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty1 linux
```

to the following:

```
c1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --autologin username tty1 linux
```

Install X by executing the following commands as root:

```
pacman -Syu
pacman -S libgl xorg xf86-input-evdev mesa vesa
```

Configure X with:

```
Xorg -configure
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

If xorg is giving you problems you can refer to the [wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners_Guide#Step_3:_Configure_X).
(If sound is also needed you can follow the steps that are given [here](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners_Guide#Step_1:_Configure_sound_with_alsamixer))

Edit your ~/.bash_profile so that when you log into TTY1 X will start automatically:

```
if [[ -z "$DISPLAY" ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
    exec startx
    logout
fi
```

Edit ~/.xinitrc and include the following (replacing celtx with whatever command starts the program you want to run):

```
exec celtx
shutdown -h now
```

Once you quit celtx Arch Linux will shut down.

You also mentioned that you would like a fast boot time. I'm not sure how this compares to what you are looking for, but on a ~7 year old computer I managed to get mine down to [23 seconds](http://picasaweb.google.com/richard92m/ArchLinux) by following [this guide](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tweaking_for_a_faster_boot_time).

Comment: For anyone wondering, this is a great way to set up a dedicated HTPC as well (I've done it with XBMC and it works great).

Answer (score 4):

You can strip any linux distro down to the bare bones - the simplest thing to do is take a distro you already are familiar with and boot into run level 1 - the standard 'single user mode'.  You won't have networking or any daemons, but you may have a desktop, depending on what you're using.  You could define a custom run level to do whatever.  Run level 4 is usually used for this.  It's undefined, so you can make it whatever you want.

Alternatively, take a look at the [linux distros tuned for smallness](http://bengross.com/smallunix.html)

EDIT
Linux is not exactly famous for speedy boot times, but the less you run at startup, the faster it will be.